# How can I add/subtract the offset value into datetime and return new datetime value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and I want to add/subtract the offset value into the `DateTime` and return new date.

Currently, I am using this

```
SELECT 
    GETUTCDATE() AS UTCDate, 
    GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'
```

which returns these values:

[image]

**Current Result** : `2021-12-28 07:19:39.320 -05:00`

**Expected Result** : `2021-12-28 02:19:39.320`

How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `cast(GETUTCDATE() at time zone 'utc' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' as datetime)`

Comment: @lptr clean and neat solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DATEADD and DATEDIFF function:

```
SELECT GETUTCDATE() AS UTCDate, GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern 
Standard Time' ,
 DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 
'Eastern Standard Time')*-1, GETUTCDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

`GETUTCDATE()` returns `datetime` type. You can use `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` instead to get `datetimeoffset` and convert it to a desired timezone.

```
SELECT 
    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS UTCDate_with_timezone, 
    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time';
```

When `AT TIME ZONE` operator is applied to `datetime` value it does not change the value, you just inform the system what is the timezone. And this timezone will be just appended to the value.